# Some methods of reading from txt files

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to learn some techniques of reading from files in C++ and I came up with this example.

Assume the following is the content of the txt file that I want to read from

```
A
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

B
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

So, what I want to do here is that if we read A, then we start to read the matrix A from below and store them into a[i][j]. And the same for B. In other circumstances we take them as exception, which we don't care here now.

The problem for me now is mixed reading. I know how to read integer and how to read strings from the file separately, like the stupid way `while(fin>>it)`. but can anyone tell me a fast way of this kind of mixed reading that I don't have to declare several reading variables (type) such as string and int?

For example, I only know how to read integer in a whole line and don't know the newline handler, which means I don't know how to recognize if we reached the end of the line or something like this:

```
    ifstream fin;
fin.open(infilename);
int it;
int arr[3][3];
int i=0, j=0;
while(fin>>it){
    arr[i][j]=it; 
      `\\I am confused at this place and don't know how to write the condition`
}
fin.close();
```

Moreover, since there are both char and int type, do I have to declare `char`? and how does `fin>>char` really work? reading char by char in a line or something else? 
I'll really appreciate if someone can guide me on this! Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code, please? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, just wait a minute :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to worry about newlines as >> skips whitespace and newlines. However, putting fin>>it in the while condition complicates things if you want different data types. You could instead read in to a character to represent each matrix, then within the loop read from fin to the matrix:

```
char c;
int mat[3][3];

while (fin>>c){
    //save c somewhere
    fin>>mat[0][0]>>mat[0][1]>>mat[0][2];
    fin>>mat[1][0]>>....;
    fin>>mat[2][0]>>....;
    //store mat 
}
```